# How to calculate angles required to lay out flat pieces in a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I want to construct a wheel made of flat pieces of wood, something like this picture:

[image: wheel]

I am unsure how to calculate the difference in angle between each of the flat pieces of wood that make up the wheel.

If I know that I will be using x pieces of wood and each piece of wood will be y centimetres long, can I calculate the angle each piece needs to be position relative to the last piece so I can layout these pieces mathematically correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Your "circle" which is actually an approximation of a perfect circle is a regular polygon with $x$ sides. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon for the relations on the angles ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Do you see that **ALL** triangles are congruent. What happens when there are $n$-sided polygon? There will be $n$ congruent angles summing upto $360^ \circ$. Each angle will be $\dfrac{360}{n}$.

To find the length of $AB$ you can use  [Cosine rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_rule).

Answer (score 1):

The angle you're looking for is

180 - (360 / x)